# ASP.NET Single Login - Is distributing session the answer

Tags: asp.net, security, session, distributed

We have 5 balanced web servers with various websites. 
What I am trying to achieve is to ensure a single login.
i.e. the same user account cannot login to the same website more than once at any given time.

The method i'm considering for solving this, is to share session amongst the servers so I can control which session is assigned to which account. I can then have control over my logins. If a user logs in and there is already a session assigned to their user account, I can just expire the first session or reject the login.

I don't want to lose the benefit of the balanced servers, so using a single Sql Server as my session state server, or a single server to handle login is not an option.

Is distributed session (something like [Scaleout Sofware](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/)) the correct approach to achieve this?

Or is there another mechanism to handle single login that i'm blissfully unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

You have two set of problems here:
1) Allowing just one connected user in a web farm scenario
2) Detecting user logoff
To solve the first the only solution is a central storage for some kind of user state, using a central server to store the ASP.Net session or some other kind of centralized user state. This central storage can be SQL Server using the native management of session state (btw also Oracle, from Oracle 11, can support session storage), the AspState service or an external solution, like ScaleOut (as you said) or its open source alternative memcached (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/). Or you can design a simple centralized web service that check active logins against a SQL Server database, this way you can also quickly create reporting tools about logged on users and so on.

Real problem, in my opinion, lies in the second part, that you need to maintain the different "wrong logoff" scenarios that are available in a web world (like closing the browser due to a crash or shutting down applications without logging off), giving you application some way to gracefully work with user that has an old session enabled (as you said simply expiring the first session can work).

Keep also in mind that using a state server like SQL server will not make you loose the balanced servers, if's the way of working to have a web farm environmet and sharing session, only problem lies in performance (if session state become large) and the cost involved in using SQL Server if you do not already have the proper license.